# Show a message where an advertisement would be when someone is using an adblocker

Tags: ads, adblock

I know AlternativeTo.net has this. When someone is on my website (http://developergenius.com) and using Adblock, a message where the ad would have been (the message would still have the same dimensions like 728x90). I would want to display maybe a short message and a small Paypal donation button. How could I do this? Thanks!

**I used the other question but it still did not work for me! That is why I posted this!**

Answer (score 0):

Well, looking at something I did a while back the Google code on my page looks something like this...

```
<div>
<script>
    /* ... some config parameters ... */
</script>
<script src="...googlesyndication source script..."></script>
</div>
```

All you want to do is to put your own content inside that div and style it to have the same dimensions as the ad unit. Google's script will replace your content with its ad when (and if) it runs.

So something like this...

```
<div>
<img src="... your own source ..." />
<script>
    /* ... some config parameters ... */
</script>
<script src="...googlesyndication source script..."></script>
</div>
```

You should be able to figure out how to extend that to include links to PayPal, etc.

**Edit for clarification:**
Of course, you could have more markup than just an img tag. What is important is to put it inside the element enclosing the ad script. Essentially, what happens is the google ad script detects which element it is inside of and it does an `innerHTML=...` on that element. So, just put your own markup inside that same element.

Comment: So if the advertisement code is (Google Adsense):                    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-7957339994747802";
/* Leaderboard - 1 */
google_ad_slot = "8758042776";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>                                                                       Where should I put the code in to display when Adblock is enabled. Thanks!

Comment: Take note of what element those scripts are inside of. Thats where the ad goes. It will overwrite everything else inside that element.

Comment: So javascript? But I am a little confused with where the text goes. For example if my text was: You are using adblock, what would the code look like? Sorry I'm not very experienced in this part. Thanks!